# How to find a colors "Upper" and "Lower" range of a color?

Tags: python, opencv

I have just started learning color filtering using opencv. I have understood most of the basics but am stuck on one thing.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Circles.png")

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_range = np.array([169,100,100])
upper_range = np.array([189,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.imshow("Mask",mask)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Where can I find the range of the colors which I want to filter?

Thank you

Comment: Convert the lower and upper range of bgr colors to hsv colors. Take any color, add +- values to bgr values, convert to HSV using cvtColor. Use those for upper and lower values in HSV. You may have to use some external tool to get the main bgr color such as GIMP or Photoshop. There are also ways to use OpenCV to measure a color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, what you're trying to do is essentially filter out a color. By default the images are represented in three channels Blue, Green, and Red. But, using this mode of representation, you cannot filter colors easily as the values are split into three channels. That's where the HSV (Hue, saturation, value) mode of representation comes to play.

The line `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` converts the BGR format image to HSV format representation.
Now, you can get the value of your required color and just add +-delta value to H channel and you can filter the color accordingly.

For example, if you want to filter green color
The BGR representation of gree color will be (0,255,0). First, we need to find the equivalent color representation in HSV that is (60,255,255). We can add a  [H-10, 100,100] and [H+10, 255, 255] as upper and lower values accordingly.

You can convert any BGR to corresponding HSV value using.

```
color_bgr=np.uint8([[[0,255,0]]])
color_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(color_bgr,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(color_hsv)
```

Please refer to this link for more details
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Comment: I think I get it

Comment: I use the formula for the upper and lower range for red. The RGB code was 255,0,0). I used the code you gave and converted  it into HSV format. I got (120,255,255). I used the formula and put the lower range as (110,100, 100) and the upper range as (130,255,255).  On this website, https://codeloop.org/opencv-python-color-detection-example/, You can find the image bellow. The output was the blue circles instead of the read circles. Why is that?

Comment: So basically RGB  code for red is (255,0,0), but in OpenCV, the channels are in the order BGR (blue, green, red), so the code for red would be (0,0,255). What you gave will be taken as Blue. That's why that is happening.

Comment: I understand the part where the OpenCV channels in BGR order. I put the numbers in and the output would be (0,0,255). I used the formula and got (-10,100,100) for the lower range and (10,255,255) for the upper range. When I run it, nothing shows up. Why is that?